# Radiometric Calibration of LandSat 8

Tags: landsat-8

Is it necessary to calibrate LandSat-8 (L1T) for the calculation of TOA radiance prior to atmospheric correction, or is it already calibrated?

Answer (score 1):

The calibration method you are talking about is called in-orbit calibration and works either with an onboard lamp-like device or the most used solar radiation method. When using the latter, atmospheric correction should be performed before the calibration to compensate for the scattering, etc. All those sensors are calibrated both geometrically and radiometrically, prior to the release of the imagery, during the test phase of the deployments.

Comment: means it is necessary  to convert OLI images in to TOA radiance or TOA reflectance for remote sensing analysis where these correction neceassary